# Validation on html page not working using data data annotations

Tags: html, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to display an error message before entering details. but it is not working. Null value is passed.

i have tried adding

```
<td>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(prod => prod.ProductCode)
     <span asp-validation-for="ProductCode"></span>
</td>
```

This is my cshtml

```
@model MVCAssignment.Models.ViewModel.ProductsViewModel
    <td>Enter Product Code</td>
    <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(prod => prod.ProductCode)
         <span asp-validation-for="ProductCode"></span>
    </td>

    <td>Enter Product Name</td>
    <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(prod => prod.ProdcuctName)
         <span asp-validation-for="ProdcuctName"></span>
    </td>
```

This is My ViewModel

```
        [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Code Required!!!")]
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name Required!!!")]
        public string ProdcuctName { get; set; }
```

Null value gets stored.

Comment: It's not something as silly as that you mean `ProductName`, not **`ProdcuctName`**?

Comment: That is how it is in the DB

Comment: Do you check `ModelState.IsValid` in the backend anywhere?

Comment: check your `mapper` class.